# Asyncio: All tasks are executed at once despite small grouped-tasks

Tags: python-asyncio

I have created all the tasks in a for loop first.

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks =[]

for i in range(100):
   task = loop.create_task(...)
   tasks.append(task)
```

Instead of executing all 100 of them, I am trying to fire just a few, say just 1, at a time so I did something like below

```py
await asyncio.wait([tasks[0]]) # just the very first one in the list
# also tried with `asyncio.gather` instead of `asyncio.wait`.
```

#### Expected behavior (at least to me)

Work with the very first task as I am only providing one task

#### Actual behavior

All 100 tasks are fired. How can I only fire just a few?

Comment: The result you see is actually the expected behaviour. Creating the task means you run as soon as possible. waiting means that you consume the result as soon as ready. That is the entire purpose of asynchronous computing.

Comment: @CarlosHorn I disagree that the above is the expected behavior. If so, why should we even pass any arguments to `wait` or `gather`? IMO the argument is there to control what tasks to run.

Comment: It is the expected behavior of `create_task`. For what you want, don’t use it. Just await the coroutine instead. `tasks.append(some_func())` then `await asyncio.gather(*tasks[a:b])`

Comment: From the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task you get `Schedule the execution of a Coroutines. Return a Task object.`, which says that the coroutine you provide is immediately scheduled and as soon as the event loop is free, it will be executed. Even if you collect coroutines in your task list, the documentation of wait https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait says that it will also run all of them

Comment: I think you are confused by the difference between a coroutine and a task. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Answer (score 0):

> How can I only fire just a few?

I think the pattern you are looking for is using a queue and having a controlled number of consumers (workers). See for example
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html